# Is it possible to view where you most recently gained reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Is there a feature somewhere that allows users to see where they gained their most recent reputation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the envelope next to your name at the top of the page. Once there, you can select different time periods to view.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your [recent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/) (found by clicking on the envelope icon near your user name at the top of each page) the reputation tab on your user profile will give you what you're looking for.

Yours is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282474/marlon?tab=reputation).